# python pandas loc - filter for list of values

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-loc

This should be incredibly easy, but I can't get it to work.

I want to filter my dataset on two or more values.

```
#this works, when I filter for one value
df.loc[df['channel'] == 'sale'] 

#if I have to filter, two separate columns, I can do this
df.loc[(df['channel'] == 'sale')&(df['type']=='A')] 

#but what if I want to filter one column by more than one value?
df.loc[df['channel'] == ('sale','fullprice')]
```

Would this have to be an OR statement? I can do something like in SQL using in?

Comment: `df.loc[df['channel'].isin(['sale','fullprice'])] `

Answer (score 141, accepted):

There is a [`df.isin(values)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method wich tests 
whether each element in the `DataFrame` is contained in `values`.
So, as @MaxU wrote in the comment, you can use

```
df.loc[df['channel'].isin(['sale','fullprice'])]
```

to filter one column by multiple values.

Comment: `df.loc[df['channel'].apply(lambda x: x in ['sale','fullprice'])]` would also work.  It is not as succinct as using `df.isin` but can be modified to check any complitcated condition depending on just one column.

Comment: Yes, definitely.